# cant access my api from localhost via NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to make an app where I fetch data from an API that I made. I need to be able to fetch this so that I can use the data in my app, it's user-specific. I see that it wants me to change the CORS headers, and I don't know how to do that.

basically:

1. I'm fetching the data on `componentDidMount`
2. parsing that data
3. using it in my state

The problem here is that when I fetch it, `CORS` blocks my request, and I have no clue as to how to change it in the `next.js` setting.

[image: the code I'm using to fetch]

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: Which framework are you using for **backend**? Its structure doesn't look like Next.js. If you are using Express, you basically need to add the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware. Things will vary according to the framework and language. Just do some research online for "how to add cors in ----- framework", you'll get many tutorials.

Comment: CORS is related to the backend. You should set it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can't access it because your backend didn't give you access to the API. I can see you used the express server for the backend. there is an awesome nodejs package called `CORS`. It solves the problem you facing by using the `app.use(cors())` middleware and configure the cors where your backend get request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways

**1.**

```
// in nodejs
app.use(cors({ origin: 'font-end url' }));

// in react
fetch('/api/api/', {
  method: '',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'back-end url'
  },
});
```

**2.**

```
// in nodejs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'front-end url');
  next();
});

app.use(cors({ origin: 'font-end url' }));
```

the difference is that in version 2 you will set the header automatically on every request. and in version 1 you set it manually in every request. if you need any further help feel free to ask :).